# Sql search in m:n table in sybase

Tags: sql, select, sybase

i have a table student class witch contains the student id and the class id

```
CREATE TABLE [StudentClass]
([StudentId] varchar(20), [ClassId] varchar(20));
```

what i want to do is to find all the classmates of a student.
for example:

```
student 1 in class 1 
student 1 in class 2
student 2 in class 2
```

if i make a search for student1 i want to get as result:
   student1 | student2
what i actually get is:

```
student1 | null
student1 | student2
```

if i had only the first row :

```
student 1 in class 1
```

the result expected would be :

```
student1 | null

select distinct s1.StudentId, s2.StudentId 
from StudentClass s1
             left join StudentClass s2 
                     on s1.ClassId = s2.ClassId and 
                        s1.StudentId != s2.StudentId
where s1.StudentId = 'Student1'
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

add this in your query

```
SELECT...
FROM..
WHERE...
      AND s2.StudentId IS NOT NULL    -- <== this condition
```

Comment: this condition will not work on this case:
    if i had only the first row:
    student 1 in class 1
    the result expected would be :
    student1 | null

Answer (score 0):

Try using `group by` instead of `distinct`:

```
select s1.StudentId as std1, s2.StudentId as std2
from StudentClass s1
             inner join StudentClass s2 
                     on s1.ClassId = s2.ClassId and 
                        s1.StudentId != s2.StudentId
where s1.StudentId = '1'
group by s1.StudentId, s2.StudentId
```

You can check it our [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63d47/1)

Comment: the result for the first example will have 2 rows student1 | null and student 1| student 2.   What i want is to get only the second row if a classmate exists, and if it doesn't something like student3| null

Comment: In the link I posted at the bottom of my answer: it finds `all the classmates of a student` like you requested. no `NULL` values. In that example student-1 has 2 classmates in class-2, and that's what the query fetches, the other two students (under `STD2`).

Comment: i tried but for me it returns them, maybe is because of my db, i'm using sybase

Comment: and also for this case http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f7fb/1 i want as result 1|null. I also check this an in my db works different :( because i get result

Comment: This case does not return `1|null` it returns an empty resultset which is perfectly fine since student-1 has no classmates in this example.

Comment: sqlfiddle can be tested on 7 different DBs (and it works for all of them except `PostgreSQL`). I'm sorry I can't help with `sybase` (unless you find a fiddler for that).